# Differences between bootstrap4 alpha and beta version breaks my ui

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is final version of bootstrap more likely to look like current alpha version (currently v4.0.0-alpha.6) or beta version (Currently v4.0.0-beta)? I am asking that because I have started a project with version v4.0.0-alpha.6 and I was quite worried when npm installed accidentally version beta instead of version alpha, because that completely broke my ui.

For example for class .btn-secondary, and I also had issues with form classes.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button>
```

Alpha version : [image]

Beta version : [image]

Comment: My guess would be that the beta is closer to the final version than the alpha :)

Comment: Yep, they're probably not going back to alpha. I used alpha for a project that is in a corporate backend, but only because it will never be updated, and it just wont matter. You shouldn't be using alphas for things that matter.

Comment: There are many [changes from alpha to beta](https://medium.com/wdstack/upgrade-bootstrap-4-alpha-6-to-beta-ca582f15ee32) as expected with any pre-release version. Please clarify the question to a specific issue or it may be closed as: **opinion-based** "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: @ZimSystem : I don't understand why my question "Is final version of bootstrap more likely to look like current alpha version (currently v4.0.0-alpha.6) or beta version (Currently v4.0.0-beta)?" is not clear enough? I mean I had a issue, so I wanted to know which version is more likely to look like to the final one, in order to avoid having a big issue in the futur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... you can't really complain on changes between alphas and beta because this is what alphas are for - to test and possibly redefine the final version... Beta is not a final version and backward compatibility is still not guaranteed. You should rather wait for release candidates (if there will be any). You can still expect some changes between beta and final Bootstrap 4 but they should be less radical than comparing alphas and beta.

That what theory says but honestly it's more like a guess. As we can't predict the future of bootstrap 4 development, I think that there isn't any truly right answer for now.

What I can suggest is to test upcoming versions of software on some test environments before updating bootstrap on production environment to avoid possible problems.

If you really need some information about **possible** upcoming changes you can browse through open issues and pull requests on [bootstrap 4 github  project](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)